# Many-to-many relationship ERD

Tags: database, many-to-many, entity-relationship, diagram, erd

Good day,

Real estate companies have several **Buildings**, each Building managed by one or more **Managers**, Managers have access to one or more Buildings. So, there is a many-to-many relationship between Managers and Buildings. It has to be a table such as **Permissions** to get rid of many-to-many relationship.

Please help me to figure it out, what is the best design for the database ?

I came up with a two candidate diagrams, which one is better? If neither of them are good, what should I change ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0l6h.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg5Sv.png

Sincerely

Comment: perhaps it's because I'm not a "gentleman," but I'm having difficulty understanding what you want the **Permissions** table to do. Your ERDs seem like you have a limited understanding of how many-to-many relationships are managed in a database. Do you want **Managers** to have many **Buildings** _through_ **Permissions**? is that what your second ERD shows? Those should be FK's, not PK's

Comment: @eriese I apologise. According to wiki, "most database management systems only support one-to-many relationships". That is the reason why I try to get rid of many-to-many between Buildings and Managers. Yes, I want to manage which managers manages which buildings through Permissions table. BuildingID and ManagerID in the Permisions table is a composite PK.

Comment: do you have an idea of what languages/frameworks and databases you'd be using to build this? I'm used to Ruby on Rails with Postgresql, which uses activerecord for really simple relationship management and handles many to many.

Comment: @eriese I am developing .NET WinForm app and using MS SQL database.

Comment: @user3715778 Modeling tools might not "support" _explicitly labeling with the many:many property_ but they support many:many. It's many:many if it isn't marked something else. Explain everything you know about "permissions". You were given a problem description. Give it to us.

Answer (score 0):

The [second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg5Sv.png) seems closest

I'd suggest moving the boxes around a little to show the hierarchy. Put Companies top and center, then on the next row, Managers on the left, Buildings on the right and Permissions between those two.

Answer (score 0):

ER diagrams are used for two different purposes.  One purpose is to illustrate the subject matter entities, and the relationships between them, as understood by subject matter experts.  This is called a conceptual model of the data.

The other purpose is to illustrate a proposed database design, one where the relationships are not only expressed, but also implemented somehow.  If the design is relational (which it usually is) many-to-many relationships are expressed by creating an intermediate table.  This is called a physical model of the data (in some literature it's called a logical model).   This is what you have done in your second diagram.

Your first diagram could be cleaned up a little by eliminating the box named "permissions", and putting a crows-foot at both ends of the line connecting Managers and Buildings.

Now to come back to your question:  which one is "better"?  It depends.  sometimes, a conceptual diagram is better for discussing the subject matter with the ultimate stakeholders:  non-technical managers who work with the data all the time, and might be called "subject matter experts".

A physical diagram is usually better when discussing the proposed design among data architects and programmers.  It explains not only how the data works in concept, but also how the database is to be built.  This kind of detail is glossed over by a conceptual model.

So you may end up with two diagrams, and use the appropriate one depending on your audience.